# DNS Configuration with VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, godaddy

I own a VPS at Go Daddy and have 4-5 website hosted on it. All Website Domain names are purchased from Go Daddy. So, whenever I buy a new domain and host a website on VPS. All I have to do is to point "A Record" to the VPS IP. Now, I have a client who has his own Domain, and wants to shift his website to my VPS. Now he is asking me for Primary & Secondary DNS Server Ip. 
I'm confused what to do??

Shall I share the IP of GoDaddy's name servers as found in other Domains at Godaddy?

Or Shall I use a Free DNS Service such as https://entrydns.net/ ? If yes, which one is good & FREE?

Comment: You shouldn't do either. Tell your customer that they need to create an A record (but a CNAME would be better) in their DNS that resolves to the ip address of your VPS. If they don't know how to do that then have them contact the Registrar where they registered their domain name to get assistance.

Comment: And what if they are buying a new domain. Then I should ask them to buy DNS Services from that registrar?

Comment: I've never known a registrar that charged for hosting the DNS zone for domains registered through said Registrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a GDY user myself, I can offer the following solution:

(It is not clear if your client needs to host just a WEBSITE on your VPS or point everything ... including Email) to your VPS).

[If you are pointing Everything]:
Provide the primary and secondary DNS servers that you are using on your VPS. Your client will simply update the NS records at their end that will basically make your DNS servers respond to queries for that domain name. You will then need to create all necessary DNS records at your end to support the domain.

[If you are pointing just the website]:
Identify an IP address -- GDY allows you upto three Static IPs per VPS -- for use for this client. Provide this IP address to your client. Your client will then update the "A" record in their DNS for the website name to point to your IP address.

Let me know if you require either more assistance or have queries on specifics.

Answer (score 2):

If your client wants to move their website to a system you manage, there is no need for them to move nameservers too. All they have to do is change the A records for their website.

As to which DNS provider to use, we don't do product or service recommendations but if we did we almost certainly wouldn't advocate using a free service (you get what you pay for after all).

Comment: Also, they are purchasing a new .edu domain, they are asking for DNS. What should i share?

Answer (score 2):

First, the basics:

A [**nameserver**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) is essentially a DNS Server that has all the information for a particular domain and/or subdomain. If the nameserver does not have the information for a particular domain, it forwards the request on to the DNS server who does. This DNS Server's IP address must be explicitly told to the nameserver.

Wherever your clients lease their domain name from, you will have to contact the company and have them set the nameservers for that domain to the DNS servers that you use at GoDaddy. I don't have proof but logically it's probably being set on a higher level (.com, .org) authoritative DNS Server.